# Efficiently reshape numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy, vectorization

I am working with NumPy arrays.

I have a `2N` length vector `D` and want to reshape part of it into an `N x N` array `C`.

Right now this code does what I want, but is a bottleneck for larger `N`:

```

```
import numpy as np
M = 1000
t = np.arange(M)
D = np.sin(t)    # initial vector is a sin() function
N = M / 2
C = np.zeros((N,N))
for a in xrange(N):
    for b in xrange(N):
        C[a,b] = D[N + a - b]
```

```

Once `C` is made I go ahead and do some matrix arithmetic on it, etc.

This nested loop is pretty slow, but since this operation is essentially a change in indexing I figured that I could use NumPy's builtin reshape (`numpy.reshape`) to speed this part up.

Unfortunately, I cannot seem to figure out a good way of transforming these indices.

Any help speeding this part up?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`NumPy broadcasting`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to remove those nested loops -

```
C = D[N + np.arange(N)[:,None] - np.arange(N)]
```

One can also use [`np.take`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.take.html) to replace the indexing, like so -

```
C = np.take(D,N + np.arange(N)[:,None] - np.arange(N))
```

A closer look reveals the pattern to be close to [`toeplitz`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.toeplitz.html) and [`hankel`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.hankel.html) matrices. So, using those, we would have two more approaches to solve it, though with comparable speedups as with broadcasting. The implementations would look something like these -

```
from scipy.linalg import toeplitz
from scipy.linalg import hankel

C = toeplitz(D[N:],np.hstack((D[0],D[N-1:0:-1])))
C = hankel(D[1:N+1],D[N:])[:,::-1]
```

**Runtime test**

```
In [230]: M = 1000
     ...: t = np.arange(M)
     ...: D = np.sin(t)    # initial vector is a sin() function
     ...: N = M / 2
     ...: 

In [231]: def org_app(D,N):
     ...:     C = np.zeros((N,N))
     ...:     for a in xrange(N):
     ...:         for b in xrange(N):
     ...:             C[a,b] = D[N + a - b]
     ...:     return C
     ...: 

In [232]: %timeit org_app(D,N)
     ...: %timeit D[N + np.arange(N)[:,None] - np.arange(N)]
     ...: %timeit np.take(D,N + np.arange(N)[:,None] - np.arange(N))
     ...: %timeit toeplitz(D[N:],np.hstack((D[0],D[N-1:0:-1])))
     ...: %timeit hankel(D[1:N+1],D[N:])[:,::-1]
     ...: 
10 loops, best of 3: 83 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.82 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.84 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.95 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 2.93 ms per loop
```

Comment: Awesome! This provided a considerable speed-up over the looping.

Comment: @jjgoings Yup, confirmed that!